# Invalid conversion from int C++ classes

Tags: c++, enums

Here is my header file. Im trying to compile this but i got an error at void init(TipMatrice tip) "initializing argument 1 of 'void graf_matrice::init(graf_matrice::TipMatrice)' " which redirects me to the main with another conversion error. I think its something wrong with my enum.

```
#ifndef GRAF_MATRICE_H
#define GRAF_MATRICE_H

class graf_matrice
{
public:
 static const int MaxN = 50; // numarul maxim de noduri
 static const int Infinit = 99999; // nu exista drum intre noduri
 enum TipMatrice
{
 MatriceAdiacenta = 1,
 MatriceCosturi = 2
  };
public:
graf_matrice();
void init(TipMatrice tip); //iniţializare graf


};
#endif // GRAF_MATRICE_H
```

Here is my main. I got an error at g.init(1) "invalid conversion from int to graf_matrice::TipMatrice" .

```
#include <iostream>
#include"graf_matrice.h"

 using namespace std;

int main()
{

   graf_matrice g;
   g.init(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Could you please help me with this cuz i dont know what is wrong. Sorry for bad language im beginner.

Comment: Why not `g.init(graf_matrice::MatriceAdiacenta);` ? Otherwise purpose of `TipMatrice` enum is not clear

Comment: Yes. Its working. Thank you so much.. I never think of this.. how easy was that

Comment: You could make `MaxN` and `Infinit` be `enum` values instead of static const ints too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've defined an enum, you'd better use its values properly:

```
g.init(graf_matrice::MatriceAdiacenta);
```

***Explanation***:  the enumerators (here `MatriceAdiacenta`) in an unscoped `enum` (here `TipMatrice`) are defined in the scope containing the `enum` (here the class `graf_matrice`). This is why you have to indicate the scope with `::`

Alternatively, if you really need to convert from an `int`, you could still do it explicitly:

```
g.init(static_cast<graf_matrice::TipMatrice>(1));
```